# How to add data to a custom HighChart's HighMaps map? joinBy?

Tags: highcharts

I created a custom map using Inkscape as described on the HighMaps docs pages at: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-maps

Everything up to step 16 seems to go smoothly.

Step 16 says that the only remaining thing to do is to add data or use the MapData option and this is where I am struggling.

How does one link the custom shapes in the map to data points?  Using the shape name in a JoinBy?

http://jsfiddle.net/GeertClaes/aWJ2D/

```
$(function () {

    // Initiate the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
        title:{text:''},
        subTitle:{text:''},
        credits:{enabled:false},
        legend:{enabled: false},

        series:         
        [
            {
                "type": "map",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "name": "Status1-CurrentPeriod",
                        "path": "M0,-695,0,-682C1,-682,2,-683,3,-683,15,-683,25,-672,25,-658,25,-645,15,-634,3,-634,2,-634,1,-634,1,-634L1,-622,108,-622,107,-694,0,-695z"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Status1-Period-1",
                        "path": "M0,-684,1,-633C15,-635,26,-646,26,-658,26,-672,14,-682,0,-684z"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Status2-CurrentPeriod",
                        "path": "M178,-695,178,-682C179,-682,180,-683,181,-683,193,-683,203,-672,203,-658,203,-645,193,-634,181,-634,180,-634,180,-634,179,-634L179,-622,286,-622,285,-694,178,-695z"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Status2-Period-1",
                        "path": "M178,-684,179,-633C193,-635,204,-646,204,-658,204,-672,193,-682,178,-684z"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Status3-CurrentPeriod",
                        "path": "M357,-695,357,-682C358,-682,359,-683,360,-683,372,-683,382,-672,382,-658,382,-645,372,-634,360,-634,359,-634,359,-634,358,-634L358,-622,465,-622,464,-694,357,-695z"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Status3-Period-1",
                        "path": "M357,-684,358,-633C372,-635,383,-646,383,-658,383,-672,372,-682,357,-684z"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Status4-CurrentPeriod",
                        "path": "M535,-695,535,-682C536,-682,537,-683,538,-683,550,-683,560,-672,560,-658,560,-645,550,-634,538,-634,537,-634,536,-634,536,-634L536,-622,643,-622,642,-694,535,-695z"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Status4-Period-1",
                        "path": "M535,-684,536,-633C550,-635,561,-646,561,-658,561,-672,549,-682,535,-684z"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Status5-CurrentPeriod",
                        "path": "M713,-695,713,-682C714,-682,715,-683,716,-683,728,-683,738,-672,738,-658,738,-645,728,-634,716,-634,715,-634,715,-634,714,-634L714,-622,821,-622,820,-694,713,-695z"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Status5-Period-1",
                        "path": "M713,-684,714,-633C728,-635,739,-646,739,-658,739,-672,728,-682,713,-684z"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Status6-CurrentPeriod",
                        "path": "M892,-695,892,-682C893,-682,894,-683,895,-683,907,-683,917,-672,917,-658,917,-645,907,-634,895,-634,894,-634,893,-634,893,-634L893,-622,1000,-622,999,-694,892,-695z"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Status6-Period-1",
                        "path": "M892,-684,893,-633C907,-635,918,-646,918,-658,918,-672,907,-682,892,-684z"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of ways:

1.) The easiest is to add it into your data using the `value` property.  This is discouraged because it hardcodes the value for the map paths:

```
"data": [
    {
        "name": "Status1-CurrentPeriod",
        "path": "M0,-695,0,-682C1,-682,2,-683,3,-683,15,-683,25,-672,25,-658,25,-645,15,-634,3,-634,2,-634,1,-634,1,-634L1,-622,108,-622,107,-694,0,-695z",
        "value": 6 // <-- here's a numerical value for this path
     }
```

2.) Seperate your `mapData` from your `data`.  Map the values in `mapData` to the values in `data` with a `joinBy`.  This makes your map paths reusable:

```
 series: [{
    "type": "map",
    "joinBy": ['name', 'name'], // <- mapping 'name' in data to 'name' in mapData
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Status1-CurrentPeriod",
            "value": 6
        }                    
     ],
    "mapData": [
        {
            "name": "Status1-CurrentPeriod",
            "path": "M0,-695,0,-682C1,-682,2,-683,3,-683,15,-683,25,-672,25,-658,25,-645,15,-634,3,-634,2,-634,1,-634,1,-634L1,-622,108,-622,107,-694,0,-695z"
        }
    ...
}]
```

<del>Update fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aWJ2D/2/).</del>

Comment: Thanks Mark!  I am after a mapData option and I am looking at 5 category areas (No fill, Red, Yellow, Green, Blue) all using the same mapData.  So how does one add their custom map to HighCharts so you can reuse it via mapData: Highcharts.maps['myCustomMapName']

Comment: @Geert, Highcharts.maps is just an empty object.  In the highcharts examples, they just use that object to store their `mapData` to then reference it later.  See here: http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js, in the highcharts example, they just grab this file through <`<script>` tags.