# Highcharts custom data for map in React TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, highcharts

How can I add custom `data` to my map `series`?

Currently, the custom data is an array-like object `data: [string, number][]` and its values look like: `[["us",0],["uk",0],...]`.

Also it looks like the data is `joinBy: ["hc-key", "hc-key"]` but I cannot even access `hc-key` in the `tooltip`:

```
tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '',
        formatter: function () {
            const country = this.point;
            console.log(this);
    // cannot access this['hc-key'] or country['hc-key']
            const info = `The value for ${country.name} is ${country.value}`
            return info;
        }
    },
// I also filter country by value like this:
colorAxis: {
        dataClasses: [
            {
                from: 0,
                to: 0,
                color: "#9E9E9E",
                name: 'No Data'
            },
```

How can I make the `series` to take in a data structure like this instead of the array `[[],[],...]`:

```
[
  {country: 'us', name: 'USA', some_value: 0, some_other_values: [{...},{...},...],...},
...
]
```

so I can display more information in the tooltip but still be able to style each country by its `some_value`?

I've looked at the answers like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829862/how-to-add-custom-map-and-custom-data-to-highmaps) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512270/how-to-add-data-to-a-custom-highcharts-highmaps-map-joinby) but they don't work for me.

I'm working with the code from this example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-zs69rw?file=index.tsx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prepared a very simple demo example which shows how to create data which will fill your requirements.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yv5fp80o/

The data:

```
var data = [{
  'hc-key': 'in',
  value: 20,
  customValue: [10, 20]
}]
```

The custom value could be shown in the tooltip by using the formatter feature: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

And here is a way how to get the full array of mapData where you can find a hc-key for wanted countries.

```
console.log(chart.series[0].mapData)
```

Comment: Thank you Sebastian! Let me try it and get back to you.

Comment: Sure, we can continue this thread here or in case of a new issue start a new topic.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was what I was looking for!